# Weird underline when hover using pseudos

Tags: css

You can see when you hover, a underline briefly flashes. I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

```
.toggle2:hover:before {
content:"➝ \00a0 Close profile";
color: #2d2d2d;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1udwnosL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
```

to

```
border-bottom: solid 0px transparent;
```

Answer (score 1):

It because one line of your css

```
  .toggle2:hover {
        border-bottom: solid 1px transparent; /*--Remove it and see if it ok for you--*/
        transition: all .3s ease-out;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add border to .toggle2. CSS is trying to animate this property as well.

```js
.toggle2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

See the fixed one below
http://jsfiddle.net/drk5rxpe/